# Graphical input from mouse with Opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, matlab

Does OpenCV has a function similar to [ginput](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html)? After the user denotes the points in the image, the ginput function can retrieve their coordinates in the program. I was wondering whether OpenCV has similar functions. If OpenCV does not have this function, can any other C++ image processing libraries offer similar functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mouse callbcack for that. See [this documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/user_interface.html#setmousecallback).